# nested class invalid use of non static data member

Tags: c++

Hi i need help with this little example.
I am unable to use `_test` from the nested class

```
class random
{
public:
    int _test;

    class nestedClass
    {
    public:
        void notify() override {
            _test = 123;
        }
    } _nestedClass;
};
```

Comment: Your edit makes the program invalid. You now need to inherit nestedClass from another class.

Comment: Removing virtual does not make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use/pass a pointer to the outer class named `random` to achieve what you want as follows:

```
void notify(random* p) 
{
    p->_test = 123;
}
```

This is because a nested class can access a non-static member of the enclosing class through a pointer to the enclosing class.

You can also pass arguments as:

```
void notify(random* p, int i) 
{
    p->_test = i;
}
```

Comment: But what if im overriding the notify and cannot add args?

Comment: i cannot change void notify() it is a virtual function

Comment: *i cannot change void notify()* You should've mentioned this in your original question.

Comment: Nested classes are not inner classes. They don't retain a pointer to an instance of the outer class; they're merely scoped within it.

Comment: @genibec746 Also the use of `override` in your modified example is incorrect. You should first clear your understanding of `virtual` functions and OOP in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the non-static member of random without a instance of random. You need to tell your `nestedClass` which `_test` it want to access. There may be many instances of `random` out there, and therefor, many `_test`s.

I think what you want is:

```
class random
{

public:
    int _test;

    class nestedClass
    {
        random& outer_;
    public:
        nestedClass(random& outer): outer_(outer) {
        }
        void notify() {
            outer_._test = 123;
        }
    } _nestedClass;
    
    random(): _nestedClass(*this) {
    }
};
```